# p-tableHeaderCheckbox all rows checked on initialization

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using PrimeNG on my project and in a component there is a p-table containing a p-tableHeaderCheckbox.

I would like to have all rows checked when my component is initialized, is it possible on how could it be done?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created an example that works, just fill `[(selection)]` with the initial values of your table.

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9sxqfs?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: I'm sorry if i was not clear enough in my post. I'm looking for the checkboxes to all be selected by default.

Comment: I think I did make the checkboxes to be selected by default

Comment: It was block by my company so i couldn't check your example. On my phone it is working, thank you very much !

Comment: if I have pagination, how can I check p-tableHeaderCheckbox when selecting all. because it seems that p-tableHeaderCheckbox only consider visible rows.

Comment: Sorry @dchang but that seems to be another question, non relative with that one.